# add border to inline-block equally

Tags: html, css

https://jsbin.com/dazugonoli/1/edit?html,css,output

How would you guys add border to inline-block div? Imagine I'm doing a calendar, the border seem repeated and not equal on each side of the box.

```css
#parent{
  width: 400px;
}
#parent > div{
  display: inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  background:cyan;
  border:1px solid;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of div you can used table for that...

Comment: @IvinRaj why? what's wrong with that?

Comment: @MukeshRam nope, not recommended.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution is to use `outline` instead of `border`

```css
#parent > div{
    display: inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    background:cyan;
    outline: 1px solid;
    text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<div id="parent"><div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>10</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: does the box-sizing need to set to border box? I can't set the parent to a width? I need to make a calendar not one row only.

Comment: @GialaJefferson, no the box-sizing does not need to be set if you want to use the outline because the outline property does not count towards the size of a box.

Answer (score 1):

Add a negative margin to the elements

```css
#parent {
  width: 400px;
}

#parent>div {
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: cyan;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a negative margin to the top and left (or right and bottom) sides:

```
margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Works if the last line contains the same or less elements than the previous lines. And also when you know the number of elements in one line - you do not use the wrapping.

```css
#parent > div{
  display: flex;      
}

#parent > div > div{
  display: flex;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  background:cyan;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;

  border-bottom:1px solid;
  border-right:1px solid;
}

#parent > div:first-child > div {
   border-top: 1px solid;
}

#parent > div > div:first-child {
   border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>
    <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div></div>
  <div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>10</div></div>
</div>
```