# flexbox equal width with certain number of item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a calendar layout using flexbox, which it will always has 7 item in a row. I'm stuck at making that without specifying a fixed with on parent.

https://jsfiddle.net/t4ay065h/

```
#calendar {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#calendar div {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42801610/add-border-to-inline-block-equally

Comment: not that, but this is duplicate of [Line break in multi-line flexbox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29732575/2803565)

Comment: `flex: 1` is effectively equivalent to `flex-grow: 1`, which tells flex items to distribute the space on the line equally among themselves. This won't get items to wrap. You need to use `flex-basis` or `width`.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this by adding width to the child elements.

```
#calendar {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#calendar div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin:10px 0 0 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(100% * (1/4) - 10px - 1px)
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4ay065h/2/).
For more reference refer this stackoverflow post [how-to-force-a-flex-box-to-display-4-items-per-row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546550/how-to-force-a-flex-box-to-display-4-items-per-row).

Comment: ur example of fiddle has nothing.

Comment: @Mellisa Updated

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add ' flex-basis: 14.28%;' on your #calendar div like this

```
#calendar div {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: 14.28%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```css
#calendar {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#calendar div {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    height: 20px;
    flex-basis: calc(100%/8);
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="calendar">
  <div>
    1
  </div>
  <div>
    2
  </div>
  <div>
    3
  </div>
  <div>
    4
  </div>
  <div>
    5
  </div>
  <div>
    6
  </div>
  <div>
    7
  </div>
  <div>
    8
  </div>
  <div>
    9
  </div>
  <div>
    10
  </div>
  <div>
    11
  </div>
  <div>
    12
  </div>
  <div>
    13
  </div>
  <div>
    14
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are adding `flex item` property of `1`, so by default it takes full `width` horizontally for `each items` according to the `width of container` and that's why `flex:wrap` doesn't works, instead add as below,

> The flex property specifies the length of the item, relative to the
>   rest of the flexible items inside the same container.

```css
#calendar {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#calendar div {
  width:14%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="calendar">
  <div>
    1
  </div>
  <div>
    2
  </div>
  <div>
    3
  </div>
  <div>
    4
  </div>
  <div>
    5
  </div>
  <div>
    6
  </div>
  <div>
    7
  </div>
  <div>
    8
  </div>
  <div>
    9
  </div>
  <div>
    10
  </div>
  <div>
    11
  </div>
  <div>
    12
  </div>
  <div>
    13
  </div>
  <div>
    14
  </div>
</div>
```